# 15 people are in a line, 5 females and 10 males. How many ways can they stand if all 5 females stand together in one block of 5 consecutive positions?

Tags: combinatorics

Is my answer correct? I did $11! * 5!$ so we treat the $5$ consecutive women as one unit, and then multiply by the rest of the men. We also multiply by $5!$ for the arrangement of the women.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is right. In general, if you wanted the number of ways to arrange $n$ people in a line where $k$ of them ($k\leq n$) must be arranged in one block, the solution would be $(n-k+1)!k!$ for exactly the reason you noted.